# How to force Angular to send cookies with Http, but without {withCredentials: true}

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have a situation where I'm sending an ajax request to an API which requires cookie data but has an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

When I add the `withCredentials` option via `http.get(url, {withCredentials: true})` it produces the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my.website.com/api/find. The value
>   of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not
>   be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
>   Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

But when I don't use the `withCredentials` option, no cookies are sent.

How do I send cookies without using the `withCredentials` option?

Comment: If you’re making a request cross-origin, the CORS protocol requirements necessitate you can’t without specifying withCredentials. Browsers will prevent it from working, because that’s what the spec requires.

So if you want to send credentials in the request, what you need to do instead is: (re)configure the CORS settings for the `http://my.website.com/api/find` endpoint such that the value of the
Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header has an explicit origin rather than "`*`".

You can make the server take the `Origin` header & echo it into the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.